# How can I secure my Firestore database agains unwanted access?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am using Firebase Firestore to store a list of transactions in a collection called `transactions` .

I use react to get the transaction from the collection, using a URL with the id of the transaction document: `http://myurl.com/h1kj54h2jk35h`

```
const id = match.params.id;
firebase.firestore().collection('transactions').doc(id).get()
```

The same way I create a new doc. I have not firebase authentication.

How can I secure my Firestore rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /transactions/{id} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

If I don't allow write, I can't create new transactions.
If I don't allow read, I can't read the transaction, but I don't want to allow the read of **all** transactions. Only the once when the id from the URL is valid.

Thus, I am looking for a way to protect my database agains unwanted document creations and unwanted document reads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for what are called [granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations). From that link:

> In some situations, it's useful to break down read and write into more granular operations. For example, your app may want to enforce different conditions on document creation than on document deletion. Or you may want to allow single document reads but deny large queries.
>
> A `read` rule can be broken into `get` and `list`, while a `write` rule can be broken into `create`, `update`, and `delete`.

So if you want to only allow creation of new documents, and getting of document for which a user must know the ID, that'd be:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /transactions/{id} {
      allow create, get;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the `{id}` placeholder saying, that only **this** id is valid? I thought that is a  placeholder fore any document inside `transactions`. This `write` would be okay, as well, if I want to be able to update the document when the correct `id` is in the url? it is secure agains unwanted writes?

Comment: Ah I see. As I understood, the `{id}` is just a placeholder for any document. The `get` specifies to get only the one document I'm asking for. While `list` is not allowed, it is not possible to run a `curl -X GET "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/test-375f8/databases/(default)/documents/transactions"` to see the database. Am I right?

Comment: It depends a bit what credentials that `curl` request uses to access the database. But any access that hits the security rules will be only be able to create new transactions or get a specific transaction that it knows the ID of already with these rules.

Comment: Would you protect sensitive data like this?